# Comparing String array headers for csv data insertion

Tags: java, arrays, string, comparison, filewriter

Hi I am trying to write a csv file with some data, I want to compare elements in the EMPTY_Columns array against the MY_HEADERS array, if they are the same I want to write in empty string, if they are different I want to write in some data.

I made a boolean function to check if headings are the same so that I could write an empty string into those columns and move to the next line

```
private boolean sameHeaders(String[] A, String[] b) {
 for(int i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i++) {
   if(a[i].equals(b[i]))
     return true;
  }
  return false
 }
```

I call this function my other one for writing the csv data into the csv

```
private void writeCsvData(File csv, List<MyReport> reports) {
  try (Buffered write = new BufferedWriter(new FilterWrite(csv))) {
    write.write(getReportHeader());
    writer.newLine();
   for(MyReport report : reports) {
      if(!sameHeaders(MY_HEADERS, EMPTY_COLUMNS)) {
        writer.write(getReportData(report));
        writer.newLine();
       } else {
         writer.write("")
         writer.newLine();
       }
      }
    writer.flush();
   } catch (exception e) {
   //errors and exception logging
}
```

I thought something like this would work but now its just writing empty strings into the csv
anyone got some pointers on where I am going wrong?

Comment: that is not the correct code, it should not compile (despite being incomplete too) - the logic seems *strange*: if ANY two columns match, return true and write something; otherwise, if none match, leave the cell empty

Comment: Can you provide the code, or pseudo-code for, _MyReport_?

Comment: @user16320675 so MY_headers is a list of headers that I want to write data in, empty_columns is a list of headers from the my_headers list that I want to write an emtpy string into, currently before I tried to implement my own check here its just writing data into the first 10 columns regardless.  this was my attempt of just trying to perform a check if the values are the same in each list, write in empty string otherwise write in data.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a basic JUnit-Test, which could help to clarify what you're trying to do. First of all I've put your code in a class called `HeaderComparator.java` with the following content:

```
public class HeaderComparator {

    public boolean sameHeaders(String[] a, String[] b) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i++) {
            if(a[i].equals(b[i]))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's basically the same method you have provided. After that, I wrote a JUnit-Test to compare 2 headers, called `MY_HEADERS` and `EMPTY_COLUMNS`, in order to test your expectation:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class HeaderComparatorTest {

    @Test
    public void testSameHeaders() {
        String[] MY_HEADERS = new String[] { "Header1", "Header2", "Header3"};
        String[] EMPTY_COLUMNS = new String[] { "Header1", "Header2", "Header3"};

        assertTrue(new HeaderComparator().sameHeaders(MY_HEADERS, EMPTY_COLUMNS));

    }

    @Test
    public void testDifferentHeaders1() {
        String[] MY_HEADERS = new String[] { "Header1", "Header2", "Header3"};
        String[] EMPTY_COLUMNS = new String[] { "", "Header2", "Header3"};

        assertFalse(new HeaderComparator().sameHeaders(MY_HEADERS, EMPTY_COLUMNS));

    }

    @Test
    public void testDifferentHeaders2() {
        String[] MY_HEADERS = new String[] { "Header1", "Header2", "Header3"};
        String[] EMPTY_COLUMNS = new String[] { "Header5", "Header2", "Header3"};

        assertFalse(new HeaderComparator().sameHeaders(MY_HEADERS, EMPTY_COLUMNS));

    }
}
```

The first test passes, which is correct according to your expectation (the headers are the same). However, the second and the third test both fail, which of course is not correct, since the headers are different and you want the function to return `false`, when the headers are not the same. So I guess, the problem with your function is, that it returns `true` as soon as two elements at the same index (e. g. `a[1] = "Header2"` and `b[1] = "Header2"` in the second and third test I provided) are the same. That is probably not what you want. You want them all to be the same, right?

So maybe you want something like this:

```
public class HeaderComparator {

    public boolean sameHeaders(String[] a, String[] b) {
        boolean result = true;
        for(int i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i++) {
            result &= a[i].equals(b[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

That makes all Unit-Tests pass. However, your function would require the two arrays to contain the columns in the exact same order.